# Data Frame In R Different Data Types

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame in R:

```
df1= as.data.frame(c(10,0.1111,4.555,3.784,9.4348,4.6232131))
```

I want to display `df1` in Markdown but I want the first value to be an integer and the rest rounded to 2 decimal places. I know that I can do by separating the data frame, but I want it all together.

Answer (score 2):

Data frames do not support multiple data types in a single column.  However since this is just for display purposes you can change the type to character then the numbers after the decimal place will not be displayed - although there may be other better solutions.

```
df1= data.frame(col1 = c(10,0.1111,4.555,3.784,9.4348,4.6232131),
                col2 = c(10,0.1111,4.555,3.784,9.4348,4.6232131))

df1 <- round(df1, 2)
df1[1,] <-  round(df1[1,], 0)
df1[1,] <- as.character(df1[1,])

df1
```